PowerApps: Storing all values from a multiple choice column into a collection
I have a choice column in SharePoint which allows multiple values from a separate lookup. When linking this to a PowerApp, is there a way to store all the values into a collection, so that when I create a Combobox dropdown, it only displays the items that are present in the list.
For example, the below selections are from a list of all UK cities



ID
Name




1
London, Birmingham


2
Manchester


3
Manchester, Leeds, Blackpool


4
London, Leeds


5
Birmingham



Can I have a dropdown in PowerApps that only includes the distinct values from the 5 records above?
ClearCollect(colCities,IncidentLog.Cities)
Collect(
colCities,
ForAll(IncidentLog,
{
CityNames: Cities
}
)
)
Do I need to loop through all the records? I've tried
Clear(colCities);ForAll(IncidentLog.Cities, Collect(colCities, [ThisRecord.Cities.Value]))

would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Hi, I haven't had any solutions yet. I've tried using the following formula:
Distinct(IncidentLog,Cities .Value)
But it combines the values for each record

I got it to work by using the Distinct and Ungroup functions. Doesn't really require a collection to be made
Sort(
    Distinct(
        Ungroup(
            IncidentLog,
            Cities
        ),
        Value
    ),
    Value
)
 Value
)

